# Solr FuzzyLookupFactory exactMatch is case sensitive

Tags: solr, lucene, autosuggest, fuzzy-search, search-suggestion

This can be a duplicate question, but couldn't find something relevant for this:

I have implemented a solr suggester for list of cities and areas. I have user FuzzyLookupFactory for this. My schema looks like this:

```
<fieldType name="suggestTypeLc" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" replacement=" " />
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

synonym.txt is used for mapping older city names with new ones, like Madras=>Chennai, Saigon=>Ho Chi Minh city

My suggester definition looks like this:

```
  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
        <lst name="suggester">
              <str name="name">suggestions</str>
              <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
              <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
              <str name="field">searchfield</str>
              <str name="weightField">searchscore</str>
              <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggestTypeLc</str>
              <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
              <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
              <str name="storeDir">autosuggest_dict</str>
        </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

My request handler looks like this:

```
  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
                <str name="suggest">true</str>
                <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
                <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggestions</str>
                <str name="suggest.dictionary">results</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
                <str>suggest</str>
        </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Now the problem is that suggester is showing the exact matches first But it is case sensitive. for eg,

/suggest?suggest.q=mumbai (starting with a lower case "m")

will give, exact result at 4th place:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":19},
  "suggest":{
    "suggestions":{
      "mumbai":{
        "numFound":10,
        "suggestions":[{
            "term":"Mumbai Domestic Airport",
            "weight":11536},
          {
            "term":"Mumbai Chhatrapati Shivaji Intl Airport",
            "weight":11376},
          {
            "term":"Mumbai Pune Highway",
            "weight":2850},
          {
            "term":"Mumbai",
            "weight":2248},
.....
```

Whereas, calling /suggest?suggest.q=Mumbai (starting with an upper case "M")

is giving exact result at 1st place:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":16},
  "suggest":{
    "suggestions":{
      "Mumbai":{
        "numFound":10,
        "suggestions":[{
            "term":"Mumbai",
            "weight":2248},
          {
            "term":"Mumbai Domestic Airport",
            "weight":11536},
          {
            "term":"Mumbai Chhatrapati Shivaji Intl Airport",
            "weight":11376},
          {
            "term":"Mumbai Pune Highway",
            "weight":2850},
...
```

What am I missing here ? What can be done to make Mumbai as the first result even if it is called from a lower case "mumbai" as query. I thought the case sensitivity is being handled by "suggestTypeLc" field I've generated.

Comment: weight will be same, because it is the same data set onto which I am querying. The only difference is in first case I am querying with "mumbai" and in second case its "Mumbai". This further signifies that exactMatch is "true" here but it is not handling case differences.

Comment: If I search for "oran" vs "Oran", I don't get any results in "oran", whereas "Oran" gets me the exact match at first place with zero weight :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden config-parameter for [FuzzyLookupFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester#Suggester-FuzzyLookupFactory) is `exactMatchFirst` which is descibed as:

> If true, the default, exact suggestions are returned first, even if they are prefixes or other strings in the FST have larger weights.

According to your config suggestions are ranked by `searchscore` field (in your config it refers to: `<str name="weightField">searchscore</str>`). This is why you when you query as `mumbai` all suggestions are sorted by weights.

But according to `exactMatchFirst=true` you will have `Mumbai` on top (for the query=`Mumbai`) despite provided weighting mechanisms. And this is actually how `exactMatchFirst` impacts the ordering.

Unfortunately I didn't find option for tuning your suggester rather than getting rid of `weightField` at all.

Try turning off weighting-by-fields or alternatively try another lookup implementation, for instance [AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester#Suggester-AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory).

Comment: **If true, the default, exact suggestions are returned first, even if they are prefixes or other strings in the FST have larger weights.** This is exactly what I need, but case insensitive.